# Anyone know well about Smilei mpi task?

Tags: simulation

I'm trying to run Smilei PIC simulation on cluster via OpenMP mpi(hybrid). But it's showing message while reading simulation parameter, after python loading, like below.

```
{^[[;33m
[WARNING](0) src/Params/Params.cpp:656 (Params) Patches distribution: hilbertian^[[0m
^[[;33m
```

In this case the task is shown as on going with `squeue` command but I can't find the job on `top` and actual job is paused like it can't escape from the loop.
Regardless the number of threads I use that always happens.

However, when I run the same namelist file on my desktop WSL with a CPU contains 8 cores, but
without mpi, the massage at the exactly same position is showing as

```
[WARNING](0) src/Params/Params.cpp:656 (Params) Patches distribution: hilbertian

[WARNING](0) src/Params/Params.cpp:1048 (compute) simulation_time has been redefined from 23561.944902 to 23561.905447 to match timestep.
```

but it keeps working well.

Does anybody know what happens on cluster in this case and how can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Smilei team provides an Element chatroom for these types of questions. Have a look to [the official website](https://smileipic.github.io/Smilei/).

I suspect you are using a job scheduler on your cluster like SLURM and your running Smilei directly in your terminal on your desktop.

When you are connected to the cluster, your located by default on the login nodes. A job scheduler is used to manage the jobs launched by the users. Jobs are executed on specific nodes called compute nodes. The `top` command is only showing what is running on the login nodes. Some computing facilities allow user to connect directly on a compute node but it is not the standard way to run simulations.

The `{^[[;33m` is only there to show the text in color in your terminal. If it is not understood, then you will see them like that.